# send SMS with SIM 900 with st nucleo

Tags: sms, at-command, stm32

i use a Sim900 of SimCOM if i sand AT command or other commands all work well, but i have a problem for sand a SMS i write this code

```
    #include "mbed.h"
#include <string>
Serial pc(SERIAL_TX, SERIAL_RX); // pc comunication
Serial SIM900(PA_9, PA_10);   //tx, rx SIM 900
string result;
void power(){
 sim_power.write(1); // accension gsm
    wait(1);
    sim_power.write(0);
    wait(13);
    SIM900.printf("ATE0\r\n");  // DISABLE ECHO 
    wait(1);}
 void clearString()
 {  result.clear();   }
 void callback_rx() { 
while (SIM900.readable()) {
  x = SIM900.getc();
  result += x;
pc.putc(x);      
   }
   }
 void sendSMS()
 {
 clearString();
 SIM900.printf("AT+CMGF=1\r"); //at command for send sms
 wait_ms(100);
 clearString();
 wait_ms(100);   
 SIM900.printf("AT+CMGS=");
 SIM900.putc('"');
 SIM900.printf("+32292*******"); 
 SIM900.putc('"');
 SIM900.printf("\r");
 SIM900.printf("Example Message SMS");
 SIM900.putc(0x1A);
 wait_ms(20000);
 } 
 int main() {    
 power();
 pc.printf("\r\n GSM 900 TEST\n"); 
 SIM900.attach(&callback_rx);  
 SIM900.baud(9600); // 
 wait_ms(100);         
  while(1) {
 wait_ms(10);
 sendSMS();  // SEND SMS     
 wait_ms(100);                 
 } 
 }
```

i see this when i send the sms but i have this strange message:

```
AT+CMGF=1AT+CMGS="+32292*"" Example Message SMS
```

i see that the system send the message later two loop, i don't know where is the error can you help me?

best regards. A.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some timing problem. You must wait until you get answer from SIMCOM after commonds,Like **"OK"** . After getting answer, you can send other commands

Comment: +1. For any handling of AT commands, it is an absolute requirement to **READ AND PARSE** all responses back from the modem.

Comment: And when you read a response, you have to see if it really is a response from the command and not an unsolicited result code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
void sendSMS(string number, string message){
  SIM900.printf("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  wait_ms(100);
  SIM900.printf("AT+CMGS=\"%s\"\r\n",number.c_str());
  wait_ms(100);
  SIM900.printf("%s ",message.c_str());  
  SIM900.putc(0x1A);
}
```

and call this function by

> sendSMS("+32292*******", "Example Message SMS");